# How many protons are pumped out per pair of electrons from NADH in oxidative phosphorylation?

Tags: biochemistry, mitochondria, phosphorylation, energy-metabolism

I have searched the web and found that 10 protons are suppose to get pumped out during the electron cycle, but i'm a bit confused.

I'm trying to count, for every complex(1/3/4), the number of protons that are reduced in the matrix versus the number of protons added to the intermembrane space. The numbers don't add up.

**my calculations:**

- complex 1: 4 protons reduced, 4 protons added.
- complex 3: 2 protons reduced, 4 protons added.
- complex 4: 2 protons reduced(not counting the ones that condens to H2O), 2 protons added.

[image: oxidative phosphorylation electron chain]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the mistake is in complex III. Look at this image from [here](http://employees.csbsju.edu/hjakubowski/classes/ch331/oxphos/olcouplingoxphos.html):

[image: electron transport system]

It clearly shows the number of protons reduced in (and taken from) matrix and number of protons pumped into inter-membrane space. So the data becomes:

**Complex I:**

*matrix:* 2H<sup>+</sup> reduced (from NADH + H<sup>+</sup>) + 2H<sup>+</sup> pumped out

*IMS:* 4H<sup>+</sup> pumped in

**Complex II:**

*matrix:* 2H<sup>+</sup> reduced (from succinate)

*IMS:* 0H<sup>+</sup> pumped in

**Complex III:**

*matrix:* 2H<sup>+</sup> pumped out (when not considering complex II, you'd count 4H<sup>+</sup> here)

*IMS:* 4H<sup>+</sup> pumped in (2 from complex II)

**Complex IV:**

*matrix:* 2H<sup>+</sup> reduced (to H<sub>2</sub>O, we won't consider it as you said) + 2H<sup>+</sup> pumped out

*IMS:* 2H<sup>+</sup> pumped in

**TOTAL:**

*matrix:* 10H<sup>+</sup> subtracted/pumped out (with 2H<sup>+</sup> to water, total 12H<sup>+</sup>)

*IMS:* 10H<sup>+</sup> pumped in

This satisfies your statement that "10 protons are supposed to get pumped out during the electron cycle". I Hope this helps ;)

`IMS = inter-membrane space`

Answer (score 3):

I just want to add a slight clarifying point to the previous member's already great answer. Keep in mind that these 10 protons that are pumped into the intermembrane space by the end are **per one molecule of NADH**. So each molecule of NADH will result in 10 protons being transported into the intermembrane space (as previously stated). For each molecule of FADH2, however, only 6 protons are pumped into the intermembrane space. This is because FADH2 skips Complex I (it feeds its electrons to ubiquinone "Q" through Complex II).