# How many protons are pumped into the intermembrane space by Complex IV in OXPHOS?

Tags: metabolism, cellular-respiration

According to [Sazanov (2015)](https://doi.org/10.1038/nrm3997), "to reduce oxygen to water, four 'chemical' protons are taken from the matrix side [...]. In addition, four protons are pumped across the membrane into the IMS". A similar statement is made in the review by [Vercellino & Sazanov (2022, pp. 152–3)](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41580-021-00415-0).

How is this compatible with only 10 protons being pumped into the IMS in total and only 2 by Complex IV (see also [How many protons are pumped out per pair of electrons from NADH in oxidative phosphorylation?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42560/how-many-protons-are-pumped-out-per-pair-of-electrons-from-nadh-in-oxidative-pho))? Does the number of 10 perhaps simply result from the assumption of a 10/3 H+/ATP ratio? What am I missing here?

(the literature on H+/2e- stoichiometry, if anything, added to my confusion)

Comment: *10 H+ per molecule NADH